# which is the best board to use with ros?

Tags: arduino, rasbperrypi, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have seen three of this boards which will go good with ros  raspberry pi  , begal bone and cubie board.  iam just beginner. i never used these boards and ros. if you know some good boards other than these just give the link.

and another question is can we use mother board powered from battery  to run ros in robots? i think this will be costly idea

if you have some minimum cost idea  to control my arduino based bot by ros just comment her

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63551/which-is-the-best-board-to-use-with-ros?/) by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use a mini-itx motherboard with a [pico psu](http://www.mini-box.com/PicoPSU-80-WI-32V) which can take 12 volts from a battery.

But it depends on your application which board is best.  If you don't want to use high processing power for a kinect and cost is a big factor then a Raspberry Pi or a beagleboard are good options.

Installation see [here](http://cooker.techsnail.com/index.php/File:PicoPSU-160-XT-plugged-in.jpg).

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0